# Manage Inventory Without Displaying Levels

Tags: plugins

I have my products set to manage inventory. Is there an option somewhere to simply make the product pages state "In Stock" rather than "X In Stock"? Or is that just set in the theme (I'm just using Twenty Twelve at the moment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a setting for this, found under WooCommerce, Settings, Inventory, Stock display format.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the excellent documentation at [WooCommerce docs](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/)?

The answer to your exact question is posted along with the needed code snippet. You can see the article [**here**](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/hide-stock-quantity-without-hiding-inout-of-stock-status/).

Comment: I had tried googling this in several different ways with no luck. Thanks for the link, but I believe the answer I posted is the correct method.

Comment: @Cory This option would also remove the 'In Stock' that you wanted.

Comment: my testing shows otherwise. It still displays "In Stock". I have it set to "Never Show Stock Amount", but it still says In Stock for variations that have stock.

Comment: Interesting, wonder why I'm seeing a different result. Anyway glad you found an answer.